# sqlalchemy - adding an arbitrary condition in the ON clause in outerjoins

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, conditional-statements

I'm very new in sqlalchemy.

I'm trying to add some arbitrary clauses in the ON clause in a outerjoin without having to rewrite my join conditions.

As an example, let's get 2 tables:

```
class adm_funcionario(Base):
    __tablename__ = "adm_funcionario"
    idFuncionario = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    nome = Column(VARCHAR(45), nullable=False)
    foto = Column(BLOB)
    apelido = Column(VARCHAR(32), default='')


class adm_funcionario_acesso(Base):
    __tablename__ = "adm_funcionario_acesso"
    idFuncionario = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('adm_funcionario.idFuncionario'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    dataHora = Column(DATETIME, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    estacao = Column(VARCHAR(45), nullable=False)
    idSessaoDB = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

if I do:

```
qr = session.query(adm_funcionario).outerjoin(adm_funcionario_acesso)
print(qr)
```

it returns the ON clause in second table as expected. But, how can I put another filter in the second table ?

I tried to use `filter` clause, but it puts the new condition in `where`, not in `ON` clause.

The only solution I found till now is to rewrite the condition completelly (sqlalchemy knows how to do the join, I'd like to just increment a new condition in this specific table):

```
qr = session.query(adm_funcionario)
qr = qr.outerjoin(adm_funcionario_acesso, and_(adm_funcionario_acesso.idFuncionario==adm_funcionario.idFuncionario, adm_funcionario_acesso.idSessaoDB > 4))
```

Is there any way to do this without full rewrite of the ON clause ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what "I'd like to just increment a new condition in this specific table" actually means. I think you mean this:

```
class adm_funcionario(Base):
    __tablename__ = "adm_funcionario"
    idFuncionario = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    nome = Column(VARCHAR(45), nullable=False)
    foto = Column(BLOB)
    apelido = Column(VARCHAR(32), default='')


class adm_funcionario_acesso(Base):
    __tablename__ = "adm_funcionario_acesso"
    idFuncionario = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('adm_funcionario.idFuncionario'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    dataHora = Column(DATETIME, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    estacao = Column(VARCHAR(45), nullable=False)
    idSessaoDB = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    # conditional relationship (give it a meaningful name)
    named_relation = relationship(adm_funcionario, primaryjoin='and_(adm_funcionario_acesso.idFuncionario==adm_funcionario.idFuncionario, adm_funcionario_acesso.idSessaoDB > 4)')


qr = session.query(adm_funcionario).outerjoin(adm_funcionario_acesso.named_relation)
print(qr)
```

You should change "named_relation" to something meaningful. You can have more than one relationship on the same table. Also, if you join on just the model, you won't get the 'and_(..)' clause. I can think of a few other solutions such as subquery, but it depends on what you really need. Also, if you make the relationship outside your class definition, you don't need to place it in a string.

```
adm_funcionario_acesso.named_relation = relationship(adm_funcionario, primaryjoin=and_(adm_funcionario_acesso.idFuncionario==adm_funcionario.idFuncionario, adm_funcionario_acesso.idSessaoDB > 4))
```